# Techniques of Integration

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following definite integral by letting $u= \pi/2 - x$.
 The integral is 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx.$$

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What are your thoughts/efforts so far on this problem? You are more likely to get a good response if we know what exactly you are stuck on.

Comment: try the half angle substitution or work with your hint

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution yields $$I = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos u}{\sin u + \cos u} \, \mathrm{d}u = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x + \cos x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

What can you say about $I + I = 2I$?

**Hint:** $2I = \frac{\pi}{2} \implies I = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: If $2I = \pi/2$ then $I = \pi/4$.

Comment: @Joel, it's getting too late over here... thanks for that. :-)

Comment: Sure thing :) @ZainPatel.

Comment: the nominator in the second integral should be $\sin$ ...

Comment: @Math-fun, no. The first line is just emphasising that $u$ and $x$ are just dummy variables.

Comment: I get confused easily :-)

Answer (score 1):

The integral $I$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx \\\\\tag 1
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(1-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\pi/2-\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Enforce the substitution $x\to \pi/2 -x$ in $(1)$.  Then, we have

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx \tag 3$$

Comparing $(2)$ and $(3)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\pi/2-I\\\\
&\implies I=\pi/4
\end{align}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Please let mw know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the very best answer I can.